# Tool (Simplify Polygon) parameter is not visible anymore

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arctoolbox

I am having a strange problem in ArcGIS Toolbox.

I am trying to use the [Simplify Polygon (Cartography)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000011000000) tool from ArcToolbox. When I open the tool, there is no possibility to input Simplification Tolerance. Please see the attached image.

I can run the tool as a batch and from the Python window without any problem.

I am using ArcGIS 10(Editor) with Service Pack 5 on Windows 7 64Bit (English) and Windows Server 2008 64Bit (German). On both machines, I have the same problem.
Any ideas?

[image]

I have reinstalled the software but the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed Internet Explorer 11 (IE11), then be aware that there is a bug registered as  [NIM097058 - The 'Simplification Tolerance' option disappears from the Simplify Line and Simplify Polygon geoprocessing tools after installing Internet Explorer (IE) 11](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDk3MDU4).

It's solved in 10.3. See bug description for workarounds in 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced same problem. Searched for help. Found this solution.
Go to Search/ Simplify line/ Right click/Batch.
There you will find option for "Simplification Tolerance"

[image]